# Simple Divisibility

Tags: java

when I run this program it get stuck in a loop of asking me to "Enter Value: " and continues to add one to the sum. Although this is exactly what it is supposed to do, if I enter a number that is divisible by 6 or 17 the loop doesn't end. Can explain why?

import java.util.Scanner;

```
public class DivisibleBy6or17 {
   public static void main(String[] args){          
   Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
   System.out.print("Enter Value: ");
   int one = in.nextInt();
   int sum=0;

   while (one % 6 != 0||one % 17 != 0) {
       System.out.print("Enter Value: ");
       one = in.nextInt();
       sum++;
   }

   System.out.print("Numbers read: " + sum);
   }
}
```

Comment: `one % 6 != 0||one % 17 != 0` try to wrap in parentheses, because it's hard to get what's going on. Also it possible leak for priority confusing issues

Answer (score 1):

You should use "&&" instead of "||":

```
while (one % 6 != 0 && one % 17 != 0) {
```

Your old condition only stops the loop if the number if divisible by 6 and 17.

Answer (score 0):

In this conditional, you are using an OR; to leave the while loop, you would have to have both `one % 6 == 0` and `one % 17 == 0`.  If you enter 102, you should leave the loop.

To fix, use `&&` instead of `||`.

Answer (score 0):

The condition has an error, the correct condition is:

```
while(!(one % 6 == 0 || one % 17 == 0))
```

or

```
while(one % 6 != 0 && one % 17 != 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you will have to use `Short-Circuit And` instead of `OR`.

`while (one % 6 != 0 && one % 17 != 0)`

Answer (score 0):

This is just a suggestion, but why don't you try to create a method that will do the task you are attempting to do rather than put the codes in the main method. The reason for this is to practice re-usability. Here is what I mean:

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
       //Enter code here
       //Method Calls here
       }
 public someMethod here(arguements if needed)
 {
  //Body here
 }
```